# XCode Create a Button Toggle that shows one image for On and one for Off with function

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, toggle, imagebutton

I am trying to create a toggle button in XCode that is an On and Off switch for toggling incoming text messages. When the feature is on the image is designed to say ON. I need to set this image property for the state that the button is on. When the image is off. The button has an image that says Off.

What is the best route to complete this code.

Ryan

Comment: Why not use a UISwitch?

Comment: Good Suggestion Dan, In all honesty I do not know much about UI Switch

Comment: It does exactly what you want it to, toggles between an "On" and "Off" setting with a tap

Comment: Thank you Dan, this is a great place to start. Ok so if I have a button well rectangle button that I am using as the toggle how would I write this coding.

Answer (score 2):

I use:

```
//Create a Switch 
UISwitch *myswitchbutton;
myswitchbutton.frame=CGRectMake(10, 10, 40, 50);
[self addsubview:myswitchbutton];
```

Then, add images

```
myswitchbutton.offImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"off.png"];
myswitchbutton.onImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"on.png"];
```

Where off.png and on.png are images with your custom design

Comment: Please format your code and provide more context for your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can add UISwitch for this :

So there can be two ways for this :

(1). Create a UISwitch object and then add it like this :

```
UISwitch *onoff = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(x_value,y_value,79,27)];
[onoff addTarget: self action: @selector(flip:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.view addSubview: onoff];
```

// This is the method called when switch state changes

```
- (IBAction) flip: (id) sender 
{
    UISwitch *onoff = (UISwitch *) sender;
    if(onoff.on)
    {
        // switch is on
    }
    else
    {
        // switch is off
    }
}
```

(2). Drag UISwitch using interface builder onto your view and connects its outlet and add target for switch events.

The on/off images for a UISwitch can be customized using the onImage and offImage properties as described [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISwitch_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

There are many sample codes which can be used for custom switch :

1.[simpleswitch](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/simpleswitch)
2. [rcswitch](http://osiris.laya.com/projects/rcswitch/)
3.[DCRoundSwitch](https://github.com/domesticcatsoftware/DCRoundSwitch)

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you , how would I set the on off image for this switch. I have an Image that says ON, and one that says Off. How do I make it so that it toggles with the code.

Comment: Number two was a little confusing for me I apologize.

Comment: Receiving an error on this line     UISwitch *onoff = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero];

Comment: check my updated answer. Here x_value and y_value are the swich origin you need to adjust as per your requirement

Comment: Check my edited answer. I have added some custom switch libraries that you can directly import them in your project by downloading them and can use custom switch provided by them also.

Comment: two errors : 1. Expected identifier or '('  2. Use of undeclared identifier 'self'

Comment: delete "(" from your code. you copied my code with the case point i mentioned there. It will work

Comment: add the switch as [your_view addSubview: onoff];
Here your_view is the view on which you need to add switch

Comment: @rynwtts have you cheked with my updated code. Is it working now ?

Comment: Hi I checked the updated code, still receiving an error message. Is there a difference between just placing this code in the app itself, or placing it in the super viewDidLoad section?